# Ionic2 templateUrl display before data loaded

Tags: ionic2

I have an Ionic 2 `Component`. It renders a html page. In the constructor, it fetches data in a promise. The html uses the data (`personModel`) and displays the values.

My problem is the html wants to render before the promise has completed getting the data, resulting in an error.

> `TypeError: self.context.personModel is undefined`

How do I make sure the html waits for the data to load before it tries to render?

Thanks

**html**

`<h2>{{personModel.firstName}}&nbsp;{{personModel.lastName}}</h2>`

**ts**

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/person/person.html',
})

constructor() {
    // promise that loads data
    this.utilityService.getLoggedInPerson().then((data: string) => {
       this.personModel = JSON.parse(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
personModel: any[];    
constructor() {
        this.personModel = [];
        // your call
    }
```

Try to initialize the object.

**EDIT:** answered together :P

Answer (score 0):

If your service can return an Observable, the async pipe might help.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

Answer (score -1):

You need to define the member variable straight away, and then assign the data to it, i.e:

```
personModel: any;

constructor() {
    // promise that loads data
    this.utilityService.getLoggedInPerson().then((data: string) => {
       this.personModel = JSON.parse(data);
    }
}
```